# What is the transaction fees for the native tokens in ADA? can i design a wallet exclusively for my own token which is in cardano block chain?

Tags: token

I am looking forward to build tokens in ADA block chain. I have some questions about the transaction fee in at this network such as do I need to sent ADA along with the tokens in order to make the transactions and how the transaction fees will be calculated in the network? Is that going to change in future? and is that possible to sent tokens for a non ada holder? Is that possible to sent ada tokens to some other wallets. for example if i want to use a custom made wallet for ada transaction is that possible to use something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the costs related to minting and trading native tokens?

Costs related to multi assets can be divided into two categories:

Fees: Sending and minting tokens affects the fees that the author of the transaction must pay. As with an ada-only ledger, the fees are calculated based on the total size of the transaction. There might also be fees for checking minting policies, but initially only multisig policies are supported, which do not incur additional fees on top of the transaction size-based ones.

Min-Ada-Value: Every output created by a transaction must include a minimum amount of ada, which is calculated based on the size of the output (that is, the number of different token types in it, and the lengths of their names).

resource 1. : https://cardano-ledger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanations/faq.html

resource 2. : https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/minimum-ada-value-requirement

Comment: Is there a way which helps me to calculate the same? i mean the transaction fee? for example I have designed a new token and i want to sent 1000 of them to some one what would be the fee which i have to pay to sent this token?

Comment: check next answer,

in your case you need the first 2 steps.
1. build a raw
2. calculate min fee

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do in my script,

1. build a raw
2. calculate min fee
3. transaction build
4. transaction sign
5. transaction submit

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee 0 
--tx-in ${tx_in} 
--tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 ${myToken}" 
--tx-out ${paymentAddr}+${myInitADA}+"${tokenAmountFinal} ${myToken}" 
--invalid-hereafter $FINALTIP 
--out-file tx.draft

fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee 
--tx-body-file tx.draft 
--tx-in-count 1 
--tx-out-count 2 
--witness-count 1 
--mainnet 
--protocol-params-file protocol.json \

to run this commands, if you are new here, you need a cardano-cli (a cardano node to run).

if you need more details, dont hesitate to ask.
happy to assist,
thomas
TTS17
theTokenSquare17

Comment: is threre a testnet calculatin? Where i can experiment with token creatin

Comment: exactly, you are right.
there is a testnet, where you can install a node and do test. you can use the link below  to request test_ADA https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/